# Find the remainder when $45!$ is divided by $47$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, factorial

> Find the remainder when $45!$ is divided by $47$?

**My approach**

I am using Wilson's theorem to solve the problem.

I reduced the expression into ($47$-$1$-$1$)!/$47!$=$(47$-$1$)/$47$!-$1$/$47!$=-$1$-$1$=-$2$

> Am I right in my approach.Please correct me if I am wrong?
>
> Please correct me how to approach towards the problem.

Comment: When one is beginning to work in number theory, it can be very helpful to avoid fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2*24=3*16=4*12=5*19=6*8=7*17=...=1\mod47$
so the product of all of them is $1\mod 47$

Comment: How 4∗14=56  mod47=1 ?I think it should be $9$

Comment: Oops, fixed now.

Comment: How is this relevant to this question

Comment: All the numbers from 2 to 45 pair off.  So 45!, which is the product of all of them, is $1^{23}\mod 47$.  That is why Wilson's Theorem is true.

Comment: @Michael. I had to give it +1 because it came up for deletion as LQ. I do not find anything LQ in it. In fact it is a wise use of Wilson's.

Answer (score 5):

$$-1\equiv46!\equiv46\cdot45!\equiv(-1)\cdot45!\pmod{47}$$

$$\implies1\equiv45!$$

Comment: (−1)⋅45! (mod47) =>1=45! Not understood

Comment: @justintakro, $$-a\equiv -b\iff a\equiv b$$

Comment: @justin In math (unlike in programming) `mod` usually indicates a congruence as opposed to calculating the remainder of integer division. [A good read for starters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). The language of congruences is more powerful, because it makes deductions like the one here simple. In a sense that `(mod 47)` tells us that we moved all the calculations to a universe where the rules of arithmetic are the same as with integers except that two integers are treated equal if their remainders mod 47 are so.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for any prime  $(p-1)^2=+1\pmod p$.
Now start with [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem) $(p-1)!=-1\pmod p$ and multiply both sides by $(p-1)$, use the above fact, to arrive at $(p-2)!=+1\pmod p$

Answer (score 2):

Wilson's theorem says $46!\pmod{47}\equiv -1\pmod{47}$. But then

$$
\begin{align*}
45!\pmod{47}&\equiv [46!\cdot(46)^{-1}]\pmod{47}\\
&\equiv [46!\pmod{47}]\cdot[(46)^{-1}\pmod{47}]\\
&\equiv [-1\pmod{47}]\cdot[46\pmod{47}]\\
&\equiv -46\pmod{47}\\
&\equiv 1\pmod{47}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I am not getting how u did [($46)^−1$ (mod47)]=46(mod47)

Comment: $46\cdot 46\pmod{47}\equiv1\pmod{47}$ so the inverse of 46 mod 47 is itself!

Comment: Not understood what you mean?

Comment: For any prime $p$ we have that $(p-1)x\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ implies that $x=(p-1)\pmod{p}$. So in our particular case $x=46^{-1}\pmod{47}$ is the number required modulo $47$ such that $46x\equiv 1\pmod{47}$. Thus $x=46\pmod{47}$.

Answer (score 0):

Wilson's Theorem states that, if $p$ is a prime number,

$$(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod{p}$$

$$(p-2)!(p-1)\equiv-1\pmod{p}$$

$$-(p-2)!\equiv-1\pmod{p}$$

$$(p-2)!\equiv1\pmod{p}$$

Since 47 is a prime number,

$$45!\equiv\mathbf{1}\pmod{47}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is the difference between your answer and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1510724/446262)?

Answer (score 0):

By Wilson's Theorem: 46!≡-1(mod 47)≡46(mod 47).

1. 46!≡46 x 45!≡46(mod 47).
2. Thus, 45!≡1(mod 47)